# Shopify CSS variable not outputting to the Shopify theme frontend

Tags: css, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am having issues using a color variable that I have created in that it will not output when I use the variable in the CSS file. For reference I am using Shopify Dawn theme as my base.

Code in the base.css file I am trying to use is:

```
.noise__background-color-1 {
  background-color: var(--color-custom-global-1)
}
```

Variable defined in theme.liquid:

```
:root{
 --color-custom-global-1: {{ settings.colors_global-custom-1 }}
}
```

Settings schema object

```
      {
        "type": "color",
        "id": "colors_global-custom-1",
        "default": "#e2ebf5",
        "label": "Custom color 1",
        "info": "This color can be used globally"
      },
```

When using the .noise__background-color-1 class I cannot get it to output the variable color. If I change it to a static color such as #efedea for example it works fine which tells me everything else is set up correctly and working. It seems to be a CSS issue I am facing which I cannot work out.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out was simply missing a semicolon after this line

```
--color-custom-global-1: {{ settings.colors_global-custom-1 }}
```

fixed version

```
--color-custom-global-1: {{ settings.colors_global-custom-1 }};
```